# Simple CSS modification - different background images with <li>

Tags: css, image, background, html-lists

I'm trying to do something relatively simple, within a list object I need to specify different background images with list objects that contain common attributes.

I know there's a way to set values per `<li>` but I'm missing the boat here somewhere.

I'm basically trying to add custom background images to: `ul.dropdown li` .

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background: #333;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}



nav{
 width: 1000px;
}

ul{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
 
 
}

ul.dropdown{ 
  position: relative; 
  width: 100%; 
 
}

ul.dropdown li{
 font-weight: bold;
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px 1px 0px 0px;
 border-color: #20587D;
 background-color: #2b75a6;
 background-image:url(images/btn-back2.png);
 background-position: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

 /*box-shadow: 5px 5px #cccccc;*/

  
  
}

ul.dropdown li.one {  }






ul.dropdown a:hover{ 
  color: #000; 
 
}

ul.dropdown li a { 
  display: block; 
  padding: 10px 10px 8px;
  color: #fff; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 2000; 
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;


}



/*li.dropdown.icon-efr {
   background:url(images/btn-back2.png) 0 center no-repeat;
 
}*/

ul.dropdown li a:hover,
ul.dropdown li a.hover{ 
  background: #20587D;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;

 
}




ul.dropdown ul{ 
 display: none;
 position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 180px; 
  z-index: 1000;
}

ul.dropdown ul li { 
  font-weight: normal; 
  background: #20587D; 
  color: #000; 

}

ul.dropdown ul li a{ 
  display: block; 
  color: #C3C3C3 !important;
  background: #20587D !important;
} 

ul.dropdown ul li a:hover{
  display: block; 
  background: #20587D !important;
  color: #fff !important;
} 

.drop > a{
  position: relative;
}

.drop > a:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 40%;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #333;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  z-index: 999;
}

.drop > a:hover:after{
  content:"";
   border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul class="dropdown">           
        <li class="drop"><a href="#">E-Forms <br>Repository </a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
              <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consectetur </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#">Downtime <br>Processing</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consectetur </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="drop"><a href="#">E-Signature<br></a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Consectetur </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">No Menu</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thx

Comment: Hello all - I figured it out: 
new css w/ bg image call removed: 



ul.dropdown li.one {
 background-image:url(images/btn-back2.png);
 background-position: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.dropdown li.two {
 background-image:url(images/btn-back3.png);
 background-position: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: new HTML

 <li class="drop one"><a href="#">E-Forms <br>Repository </a>
          <ul class="sub_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Consectetur </a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>

Comment: <li class="drop two"><a href="#">Downtime <br>Processing</a>
          <ul class="sub_menu">
           <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Lipsum</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Consectetur </a></li>
          </ul>
         </li>